# How to get 'ready' value from async input in Angular

Tags: angular

In my parent component i'm passing async value as an input

```
<app-mycomponent [numberVal]="(numbers$ | async).total" [max]="max"></app-mycomponent>
```

In my child component i need to use this "numberVal" value to do some calculations but when i log this on console ngOnInit() value is not ready, so it's null.

```
  @Input() numberVal: number; // total products

   ngOnInit(): void {
console.log(this.numberVal) 
  }
```

I tried to use ngOnChanges but it did not work either.

Comment: see this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62684444/angular-async-input-undefined-in-ngoninit

Comment: It makes sense that it is null when the component is created. Use `ngOnChanges` instead and check if numberVal is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we have to do with `async` operation, it makes sense that the value is *null* when the *component* is created.

For getting the value after the `observer` is completed, you need to implement `ngOnChanges` in this way:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['numberVal']) {
      this.numberVal = changes['numberVal'].currentValue;
      console.log(this.numberVal);
    }
}
```

I have created a simple [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-brzqju) project for demonstrating this.